# create hashmap from dictionaries python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, hashmap

I have dictionaries like

```
    {
    {'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
    'index_price': 23822.86,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 0.5},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-30JUN23-40000-C',
    'index_price': 23813.52,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 0.1},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
    'index_price': 23812.99,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 6.0},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-26MAY23-18000-P',
    'index_price': 23817.83,
    'direction': 'buy',
    'amount': 0.3}
}
```

I want output like , group by dates and adding amount in dictionary.

```
{ 24FEB23 : 6.5, 30JUN23: 0.1 , 26MAY23:0.3}
```

Basically to sum up the values from the string date

```
instrument_date= instrument_name.split()[1]
```

Is there any better way other than using for loop in this.

Comment: You can create a pandas dataframe from the data, and use the groupby feature - might be a bit faster than looping

Comment: Could you please assist on that using pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, you can solve this using a for loop (with a defaultdict)

```py
dat = [{'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
        'index_price': 23822.86,
        'direction': 'sell',
        'amount': 0.5},
       {'instrument_name': 'BTC-30JUN23-40000-C',
        'index_price': 23813.52,
        'direction': 'sell',
        'amount': 0.1},
       {'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
        'index_price': 23812.99,
        'direction': 'sell',
        'amount': 6.0},
       {'instrument_name': 'BTC-26MAY23-18000-P',
        'index_price': 23817.83,
        'direction': 'buy',
        'amount': 0.3}]
```

Solution with loop:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
def sum_dates(dat):
    out = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for dct in dat:
        out[dct['instrument_name'].split('-')[1]] += dct['amount']
    return dict(out)

%timeit sum_dates(dat)
>>> 1.82 µs +/- 292 ns per loop (mean +/- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Solution with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
df['date'] = df['instrument_name'].str.split('-').str[1]

def sum_dates_pandas(df):
    return df.groupby('date')['amount'].sum().to_dict()


>>> %timeit sum_dates_pandas(df)
219 µs +/- 18.6 µs per loop (mean +/- std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Seems the first solution is the fastest

Comment: This is expected..

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the problem with a for loop here. If dicts is a list of your dictionaries, then

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)
for x in dicts:
    d[x['instrument_name'].split('-')[1]] += x['amount']

# d = {'24FEB23': 6.5, '30JUN23': 0.1, '26MAY23': 0.3}
```

Should be fast enough, unless you are dealing with massively big inputs

Answer (score 0):

As oskros suggested, you might use pandas for this like so. Note that I've changed your `{}` to `[]` so it is a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
    'index_price': 23822.86,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 0.5},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-30JUN23-40000-C',
    'index_price': 23813.52,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 0.1},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-24FEB23-24000-C',
    'index_price': 23812.99,
    'direction': 'sell',
    'amount': 6.0},
   {
    'instrument_name': 'BTC-26MAY23-18000-P',
    'index_price': 23817.83,
    'direction': 'buy',
    'amount': 0.3}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.groupby('instrument_name')['amount'].sum())
```

Outcome:

```
instrument_name
BTC-24FEB23-24000-C    6.5
BTC-26MAY23-18000-P    0.3
BTC-30JUN23-40000-C    0.1
```

Comment: Please see the output, i want to split the date and then add the same. Not by instrument name.. By Instrument date.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. See the answer of Oskrom, he provided a complete answer.